# Quartz on a lightly loaded server

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net

I have several important Quartz events that MUST go off at specific times of the night. Lately I have been noticing that not all the events are run. I have a feeling that overnight our server load is very light (ie. zero users) and that the web server kind of goes to sleep, and hence so does Quartz. Does this seem plausible? I am using Quartz.net within the web server, and not as a separate service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is plausible. In general, it is considered a bad practice to have IIS run scheduled tasks, that is a job better left for a Windows Service, or the built-in Windows Scheduled tasks (which has been much improved for Windows Server 2008).

Your worker process might have been shut down because there are no load. By default, IIS shuts down worker processes after 20 minutes without ingoing requests (you can alter this in the Application Pool settings). Also, worker processes are likely to be restarted after a certain amount of time or requests, or if they consume too much memory.

A quick-fix for your specific problem might be to use the Windows Task Scheduler to request the site periodically to keep it alive - or have it request a URL that triggers your task at the predefined time.

Comment: Very interesting. Is extending this worker process to 24 hours a reliable workaround we can look at?

Comment: @Julie, no, I wouldn't recommend that. A scheduled task to keep the site alive should be more reliable.

Comment: Tx for advice so far... You means that a workaround would be to schedule a dummy call to our own site every 10 minutes. eg. Make a call to /index.html every 10 minutes, and then at least nothing will go to sleep?

Comment: Yes, a call every 10 minutes should keep the site alive.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net, by default, will shut down AppDomain's after a period of inactivity.

The recommended course of action is to implement timed events either in a Windows Service or as an executable launched from Window's Scheduled Tasks.

It is also possible to change the IIS configuration so that it will not shut down your AppDomain.  How exactly this is accomplished varies between versions of IIS, but instructions can easily be found by searching.